# Consulta [HTML]

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema.. recien estoy empezando a ver html y estoy siguiendo un cursito en un pdf. El problema es que puse dos botones, uno para cambiar el color y otro para cambier el size. El primer boton funciona pero el segundo no.

```js
function cambiarColor() 
{   var tit=document.getElementById('titulo');   
    tit.style.color='#ff0000'; } 
 
function cambiarTamanoFuente() 
{   var tit=document.getElementById('titulo');  
    tit.style.fontSize=1; }
```

```html
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Problema</title> 
        <script src="funciones.js"></script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1 id="titulo">Este es un titulo dinamico</h1>  
        <input type="button" value="Cambiar Color" onClick="cambiarColor()"> 
        <input type="button" value="Cambiar Color" onClick="cambiarTamanoFuente()"> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te funciona por que se te ha olvidado concatenar la unidad de medida (px) la cual es necesaria para cambiar tamaños, deberías hacerlo así:

```js
function cambiarColor() 
{   var tit=document.getElementById('titulo');   
    tit.style.color='#ff0000'; } 
 
function cambiarTamanoFuente() 
{   var tit=document.getElementById('titulo');  
    tit.style.fontSize=1 + 'px'; }
```

```html
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Problema</title> 
        <script src="funciones.js"></script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1 id="titulo">Este es un titulo dinamico</h1>  
        <input type="button" value="Cambiar Color" onClick="cambiarColor()"> 
        <input type="button" value="Cambiar Color" onClick="cambiarTamanoFuente()"> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder!!

Comment: @facuk si la respuesta te sirvió te invito a que la marques como aceptada para que los futuros desarrolladores que tengan un problema similar sepan cual es una solución correcta, **Es importante que leas [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**, saludos !

Answer (score 1):

```
function cambiarTamanoFuente() {
  var tit=document.getElementById('titulo');
  tit.style.fontSize='20px';
}
```